# Box2D Static BodyType collision

Tags: performance, box2d

I know, that when two solid bodies collide, they won't affect each other, but does it affect performance? I don't think it should, but my game seems slower, when they overlaps.
I am also using SpriteBatch to draw textures on them.

Comment: You could easily answer the last part of your question by disabling the sprite drawing. As for colliding, yes, it uses more CPU than when things are not colliding, but you should not notice much difference until there are hundreds of bodies colliding, and many are collided together, ie. in the same pile.

Comment: But what if I have a whole map which is consisting of square bodies (SolidBody type). Do they actually collide and lower performace?

Comment: Yes. You can't have collision checking without using some CPU time. If you are talking about a large landscape made from static tiles, you could probably improve it by making them into edge outlines only, like in the image in this post: http://www.box2d.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=8&t=3456&p=17422#p17422